# .htacess redirect two domains to a single one, with params

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've got currently two domain names pointing to a same application. One is a french url (A) the other domain an english one (B).

We now want to use a third domain name (C) that will be the main one.

So, I need in my .htaccess redirect

`A.fr/my/great/url` to `C.com/my/great/url?locale=fr`

and

`B.com/my/great/url` to `C.com/my/great/url?locale=en`

How to do so in a my .htaccess?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the htaccess in your document root add:

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect from A.fr
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} A\.fr$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://C.com/$1?locale=fr [L,R=301,QSA]

# redirect from B.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} B\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://C.com/$1?locale=en [L,R=301,QSA]
```

The rules need to be *before* any existing rules, especially ones that do routing.

Comment: Hey, I don't see C.com in these rules. And tryin your code make infinite redirections.

Comment: @CoBaLt2760 Yeah, I forgot to add those, edited the rules above

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple index.html file width Meta Refresh Tag

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks to @Jon Lin, the correct answer is:

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect from A.fr
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} A.fr$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ C.com/$1?locale=fr [L,R=301,QSA]

# redirect from B.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} B.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ C.com/$1?locale=en [L,R=301,QSA]
```